# iReports won't read my JavaBeans datasource, but it does load the class file

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've been losing my mind over this for the past week. I've tried tons of tutorials and forums, but nothing works.

Here's the overview: I want to display JavaBean objects in a simple table. I've created the JavaBean object, I've set the classpath, but iReport just won't work with it no matter what I try. Here's the entire Java code:

```
package mypack;
public class Person
{

    private String name;

    private static Person[] data = {new Person("John"), new Person("Mark")};


    public Person() {}

    public Person(String newName) { name = newName; }


    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String newName) { name = newName; }


    public static Person[] getPersons() { return data; }
}
```

In iReport, I've created a new "JavaBeans set datasource" connection. Here's how it's filled:

[image: iReport]

However, when I click on "Test", nothing at all happens. No error but no data either. If Ichange the name of the factory class, then I will get the "class not found" exception, so iReport obviously did load my class, but it's still not working.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong in the Java file, because iReport seems to load it fine, but can't "talk" with it.

I've created the Java class with Eclipse Juno and I'm using iReport 4.6.0. Any help woud be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. I was building Java file against 1.7, which iReports can't seem to read it seems. Building for 1.6 solves the problem and the above code works fine.

Comment: ran into the same problem and your solution worked for me too. ireport should throw some kind of exception instead of silently not working.